# why is indexing applied to a specific column and not on every column by default?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have read about indexing in DB, the point i don't understand is that why do we need to specify index to a particular column, if it makes the search fast, why it is not by default to all columns? is it possible to create multiple indexes in one table?

Comment: While it makes search fast it makes inserts and updates slow...

Comment: And indices require additional space on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are n no. of indices and when you perform any save/update operation that modifies keys, it does it n times, hence produces an excessive write lock. When you will perform such operation, you will observe that reads would be faster with no indexes than when trying to update consistently with too many indexes. So in order to perform indexing, you should keep track of indexes else there would be a great performance issue (sake of RAM and write lock).

Comment: much clear now with indexing, one question related to mongo, i have over 150 tables, and i have to add index to a column, is there any way to do this with one go?

Comment: what do you need? create an index on same field (not column) for each collection (not table), or create an index across your collections?

Comment: Thanks!! @Anukool, first of all, i would like to clear that what you should call a table is a collection in mongo and what you call a column would be a value of certain key. So now please put up your question in the above terms.

Comment: db.collection.createIndex(). As you can see createIndex is a method on a particular collection.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, just switched form mysql to mongo, I have to apply an index to a key in all 150+ collections.  by db.createIndex() method, I have to write this 150+ times (for every collection). just need to know if there is an easy way to apply index to all these tables at once.

Comment: Well You can do something like this

db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collName) { 
    // Create your index
});

Comment: i have created collections, now i need to add index to one of key, i am using mongoose. when i try createIndex() method it throws an error schema.createIndex is not a function. also i used schema.index() method but it is not working either.

Comment: createIndex is a method on collection, for mongoose, you have to do schema.index()

Answer (score 2):

To resume :

Using indexes improves performances on read query, because mongodb doesn't read entire collection when searching documents. It also improves sorting.

But these improvments have a cost :

- Indexes use disk/memory space.
- Delete, insert and update operations will be longer : on each insert, delete or update operation, mongodb must update all you concerned indexes.
- There are multiple indexes type, and some of them (compound index ie) can have planty of combinations

For these reasons (but not only), by default only index on _id field (as it need to be unique) is created on collection creation.

Comment: I have created an index for one key, the index is showing when i am using getIndexes() method, but when i am using geonear query, it is throwing an error : unable to find index for $geoNear query. can you please explain the cause of this error.

Comment: To query with geonear (command or aggregation stage), you need a particular geospacial index [2d](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2d/) or [2dSphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/)

Comment: i have added this index (2dsphere), it shows when i run db.collection.getIndexes() , but when i query with geonear then it shows the error : unable to find index for $geoNear query.

Comment: think you have to open another topic, with data sample, command run to create index, result of db.collection.getIndexes() and $geonear query used

Comment: post a comment here when it's done, i will take a look